# How can I find the value of the histogram?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, histogram

I use matlab GUI. This is my code:

```
data = guidata(gcbo);

for i = 1:5
  citra3{i} = imread(['D:\,,TA,,\Skripsi Saya\Minggu, 6 Mei 2012\Tugas_Akhir1\Pelatihan\temulawak\' num2str(i) '.jpg']);

    graylawak{i}=rgb2gray(citra3{i});
    citra3{i} = imresize(graylawak{i}, [20 15]);
```

How can I find the value of the histogram of images without having to use imhist? because the value of the histogram would I use to calculate the similiarity. I am very grateful for the help you give.

Comment: sorry, your question seems a little vague (at least to me). Could you explain what you did, what didn't work and what you want to achieve? thanks

Comment: looking for value histogram (probability) of the image. can you help me?
how to find the value of the histogram (probability) of the image. because I have not found a reference source to search for the value of the probability histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to get a histogram of the grey-values in each element of your citra3 array. 
To achieve this you could do:

```
% This turns the 2D image into a vector:
foo = reshape(citra3{i},1,numel(citra3{i}));
% As the pixel values are in uint8, they can have 8 bit (2^8=256) different values.
% Make one bin for each possible pixel value:
numberOfBins = 256;
% Convert the image data (uint8) to double precision values:
foobar = double(foo);
% Calculate the distribution of values within the bins:
[n,xout] = hist(foobar,numberOfBins); 
% Plot the resulting histogram:
bar(xout,n)
```

Does this answer the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand, there was an error like this:

??? Error using ==> mtimes
Integers can only be combined with
integers of the same class, or scalar
doubles.

Error in ==> hist at 78
        xx = miny + binwidth*(0:x);

@solimanelefant

Comment: Sorry I didn't check carefully. Image data is in the numeric class "uint8", an 8-bit integer. The hist function expects data to be passed in the numeric class "double". You have to convert to double before executing hist. I updated my post. Does it do what you'd like it to?